# Background task on watchos throws an error because there is no bktaskapp file

Tags: watchos

When it's time for a scheduled background task I get error

```
[bg_app_refresh] -[WKRefreshBackgroundTask _userInfo]_block_invoke:199: Reading userinfo data from path: /Users/alex/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9E80F1E5-A033-48D2-9B28-2575C5BD4CE4/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/0B304687-E00E-415C-AF9D-331A324DFAEA/Library/com.apple.watchkit/bktaskapp_D35F613C-49E7-4889-8AFE-9A0B2202442E, failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “bktaskapp_D35F613C-49E7-4889-8AFE-9A0B2202442E” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/alex/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9E80F1E5-A033-48D2-9B28-2575C5BD4CE4/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/0B304687-E00E-415C-AF9D-331A324DFAEA/Library/com.apple.watchkit/bktaskapp_D35F613C-49E7-4889-8AFE-9A0B2202442E, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000159f090 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

What is this file? "bktaskapp_D35F613C-49E7-4889-8AFE-9A0B2202442E"

Comment: Im facing same issue, did you find a solution

Comment: @AhmetAydemir, nope